Preservation of exact equations of motion in time-dependent perturbation theory for the Hamilton-Jacobi equations
From the Hamilton-Jacobi formalism the solution for the unperturbed hamiltonian $H_0$ has a generating function $S(q,\alpha,t)$ such that
$$K_0 = H_0(q, \frac{\partial S}{\partial q},t) + \frac{\partial S}{\partial t}= 0.$$
For the dynamics generated by $H_0$, $(\alpha,\beta)$ are constants since $\dot{\alpha}  = -\frac{\partial K_0}{\partial \beta } = 0$ and similarily for $\dot{\beta} = \frac{\partial K_0}{\partial \alpha}=0$. Futhermore this transformation $(q,p)$ -> $(\alpha,\beta)$ preserves the equations of motion.
For the new Hamiltonian $H = H_0 + \Delta H$, $(\alpha,\beta)$ are still valid coordinates such that the exact equations of motions for those variables are now given by $\dot{\alpha}  = -\frac{\partial K}{\partial \beta }$ and $\dot{\beta}  = \frac{\partial K}{\partial \alpha }$.
where
$K = K_0 +\Delta H$. Why is this the case, how come these new equations for $(\dot{\alpha}, \dot{\beta})$ will give the exact equations of motion for $(\alpha,\beta)$?
Reference: page 2 of https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-09-classical-mechanics-iii-fall-2014/resources/mit8_09f14_chapter_5/


In a perhaps more logical notation, let
$$H(q,p,t)=H_0(q,p,t) + \Delta H(q,p,t).\tag{A}$$
Let the Kamiltonian
$$K(Q,P,t)~:=~\Delta H(q,p,t) \tag{B}$$
be designed to yield the interaction picture, i.e. the un-perturbed
Kamiltonian
$$K_0~\equiv~ 0\tag{C}$$
is trivial.

Now perform a canonical transformation (CT)
$$(q,p,t)\quad\longrightarrow\quad(Q,P,t)\tag{D}$$
with type-2 generating function $S(q,P,t)$ satisfying the un-perturbed Hamilton-Jacobi (HJ) eq.
$$\begin{align} \frac{\partial S}{\partial t}
~=~&K-H~\stackrel{(A)+(B)+(C)}{=}~K_0-H_0\cr
~=~&-H_0(q,\frac{\partial S}{\partial q},t).\end{align} \tag{E}$$

Note that the coordinate transformation (D) is both a type 2 CT wrt. the perturbed pair $(H,K)$ and the unperturbed pair $(H_0,K_0)$ because $K-H=K_0-H_0$.

The un-perturbed Kamilton's equations read
$$ \frac{dQ^i}{dt}~=~\frac{\partial K_0}{\partial P_i}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\frac{dP_i}{dt}~=~-\frac{\partial K_0}{\partial Q^i}.\tag{F}$$
The perturbed Kamilton's equations read
$$ \frac{dQ^i}{dt}~=~\frac{\partial K}{\partial P_i}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\frac{dP_i}{dt}~=~-\frac{\partial K}{\partial Q^i}.\tag{G}$$
That they have the exact same form as Hamilton's equations is the defining property of a CT, cf. OP's title question.

Note that even though the new coordinates $(Q,P)$ are exactly the  same for the un-perturbed and the perturbed system, the solutions for the un-perturbed eq. (F) and the perturbed eq. (G) are not (necessarily) the same.



The transformation is canonical with respect to $H_0$ only. Why does adding $\Delta H$ yields these equations ? We could have gotten for example that the new K requires an additional generating function, or anything else for it to be canonical. Wouldn't a starting point be the condition that a transformation is canonical if $p\dot{q} - H_0 = P\dot{Q} - H_0 +  \dot{F}$ ? In other words why being canonical for $H_0$ implies it being canonical for $\Delta H$ but now with respect to the Kamiltonian $K = H_0 + \dot{S} + \Delta H$ ?

Where is the answer to : why being canonical for $H_0$
implies it being canonical for $\Delta H$
but now with respect to the Kamiltonian $K = H_0 + \dot{S} + \Delta H$
?

Ah, could you elaborate on point 3. How can I note that (D) is a canonical transformation for K from this ? This would answer my question, thank you

I updated the answer.
